# Deleting site-specific cookies in chrome using python

Tags: python, google-chrome, cookies

I regularly use citrix via chrome. The app is quite buggy, and when it crashes I often have to clear the site-specific cookies to start it up again. I can do that in chrome but it's a bit of a pain, so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do it in python, using Requests or some other method?

I can get to the relevant cookies in chrome via chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=, and this page has a "Remove All" button that does the job. But I don't know how to make python press the button. Or is there a python module that would edit chrome's cookie file (whatever way they are stored) directly?

Any help gratefully received

Comment: Have you considered just using the application in Chrome's incognito mode? Once you close the window, cookies are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome stores Cookies in a SQLite database. On Windows this is located at `C:\Users\<Your Username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default.`, and on Linux it's at `/home/<Your Username>/.config/google-chrome/default`.

After clearing them manually with the remove all button, you could copy the resulting Cookie file to a separate location. Then whenever you need to remove your cookies, you could overwrite the cookie file with the one you set aside.

A somewhat more complicated, but better solution would be to modify [this script](https://bitbucket.org/richardpenman/browsercookie/src/4c2edb40c4f933a759bfe8c41bce1a124775ff81/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-122) that gets cookies from the SQLite file. The SQL commands would need to be changed to delete cookies instead of retrieving them. Using this method would allow you to only delete the cookies you need, instead of deleting all of the cookies.